# How to install something from one computer to all computer?

Tags: software-installation

In my college lab all computers are connected with LAN,so i want to install 'spyder' software from one computer to all computer.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you the administrator? If not, get permission first.

Comment: _I installed `Ubuntu` in each computer of my college lab with same username (CSLAB) and same passwrod (E201) and all the computers are connected with the same LAN. So how can i become a administrator for each computer users ?_

Comment: @AbhishekKamal, a word of advice.. Don't post real usernames (and passwords??) on public websites. And also, if "E201" really is your admin-password, consider replacing it with something a lot more secure!

Comment: Solutions such as Ansible and clusterssh (mentioned below) use SSH to connect to the computers you want to manage. You can (and should) set up password-less access which affirms trust among the computers (ie your computer is trusted by all managed computers) for automation to work smoothly.

Comment: An "administrator" on Ubuntu is nothing more than someone who can become root, e.g. with "sudo -s" (and then run "apt" to install software).   Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen What am i doing in first place ?

Answer (score 14):

For this, my preferred solution is Ansible (https://www.ansible.com/). It let's you automate any kind of configuration or installation across as many computers as you could possibly want. Another upside to Ansible is the community which has already made a lot of robust scripts available, for performing most configuration and installation tasks.

[This looks like a fairly comprehensible tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/linux-tutorial-install-ansible-configuration-management-and-it-automation-tool/) to get you up and running with Ansible.

However, if this is just a one-off command you want to run on multiple computers, you're better off just [scripting it in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/automatically-run-commands-over-ssh-on-many-servers).

Answer (score 12):

If it is just a couple of simple commands you need to execute and you don't want to configure complex automation software (like ansible, salt or puppet) you could use `clusterssh`.

Open a command line window to install

`sudo apt-get install clusterssh`

now you can open a connection to a number of hosts, like this

`clusterssh -l username labhost1 labhost2 labhost3`

clusterssh will then give you a window to enter your commands, but also one terminal window for each host you connect to - so you can see what actually happens!

[image: ClusterSSH example]
*In this example, you can see the command window with "apt-get update" to the right and all the cluster terminals to the left.*

Should one of the hosts have an issue, you can see the error message immediately and click on the corresponding terminal to remedy the situation.

You can also write a list for `clusterssh` to connect to:
Open your favorite editor and write to `$HOME/.clusterssh/clusters`

```
collegelab labhost1
collegelab labhost2
collegelab labhost3
```

then connect with

```
clusterssh -l username collegelab
```

---

Further reading

- [Man Page](https://www.mankier.com/1/cssh)

Comment: In fairness, you could probably do the same from Ansible commandline as simply and easily as you suggest for clusterssh.. :) Put your hosts in an inventory file, and then run the command from terminal, something like `ansible inventory -a 'shell command goes here'`

Comment: @tplive sure, you can do that with ssh commands alone as well, there is also `pssh`.... but with clusterssh you have immediate feedback and a way to stop/remedy if there is an issue. This is just an alternative way to go about things. Personally I'd prefer a software automation (like ansible).

Comment: _In my college lab, each computer have  **same user name and same password**. so can i use `clusterssh` or `ansible` for  that ?_

Comment: @RobertRiedl and that's why I upvoted your answer.. :)

Comment: @AbhishekKamal Absolutely! For the smoothest experience with password-less login, put your public ssh key into the authorized_keys file on each computer using `ssh-copy-id` or similar.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Wow, and you should have also extended your answer to include a simple command example for clusterssh to execute though you provided a link already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic sequential solution assuming you know all the hostnames or ip addresses of the computers on the network and you have enabled public key authentication. See here for more details - https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1

1. Create a new file e.g. `hosts.txt`
2. Populate each line of said file with the ip addresses or hostnames of the boxes on your LAN
3. Iterate over each line in the file and install the software on the host like so

`` for i in `cat hosts.txt`; do ssh $i apt-get --assume-yes install spyder; echo ; done ``

Comment: _@bunnydrug The hostname for all computers in my LAB is CSLAB and password is E201. so what should i write in `hosts.txt` file_